# Android 10 MediaStore file permission

Tags: android, android-10.0, mediastore, scoped-storage

I have a problem with image permissions only in Android 10. I state that the proplema is only with android 10, in fact with android 11 and with android 9 and earlier the write and read permissions are enabled.
In the manifest I have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="28"/>` and in application `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` as the documentation says.
My compile version is 30 an target is 30. Even bringing back the target version to 29 I have the same result.
Files are inserted via intent:

```java
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
      photoUri = activity.getContentResolver().insert(
          MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL),
          contentValues
      );
    else
      photoUri = activity.getContentResolver().insert(
         MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
         contentValues
      );

    final Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);
    activity.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA_KEY);
```

and instead the get happens like this:

```java
@Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if (requestCode != REQUEST_CAMERA_KEY || resultCode != RESULT_OK)
      return;
    // use ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P
    final Bitmap bitmap =BitmapProvider.getBitmap(contentResolver, photoUri);
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(photoUri, null, null, null, null);
    String value = null;
    if (cursor == null) {
      value = photoUri.getPath();
    } else {
      cursor.moveToFirst();
      int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
      value = cursor.getString(idx);
    }
    cursor.close();
    File file = new File(value);
    // Android 9 and < true true
    // Android 10 false false
    // Android 11  true true
    System.out.println(file.canRead() + " " + file.canWrite());
    try {
      final FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file); // Android 10 generate open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) exception
      bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fileOutputStream);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

get the bitmap:

```java
public Bitmap getBitmap(
      final ContentResolver contentResolver,
      final Uri photoUri){
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
      final ImageDecoder.Source source = ImageDecoder.createSource(contentResolver, photoUri);
      try {
        bitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source);
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    } else {
      InputStream inputStream = null;
      try {
        inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(photoUri);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } finally {
        if (inputStream != null) {
          try {
            inputStream.close();
          } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return bitmap;
  }
```

I would need an explanation for this despite having followed the documentation, and maybe an explanation. Thank.

Comment: Sorry, but what is your problem exactly? What does not work? Come to the point please. Where are you talking about?

Comment: i need to read and write that file to compress the image and edit it. And display the file size before and after.

Comment: Yes.. and... You still did not tell which problems you encounter doing so. And why didnt you post onActivityResult code?

Comment: i have `open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)` when I instantiate the `new FileOutputStream(file)` for the `bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fileOutputStream)`

Comment: Please put complete code in your post in an onActivityResult body. Now we dont even know what `file' would be. Also put the errors in your post. Write a to the point post. Ant tell exactly what the code should do.

Comment: i have udated my code

Comment: I do not know what is BitmapProvider. Further you did not tell why you need a cursor or mess around with getPath(). Or mess around with the File class. And you did not tell which errors you have or for what you expect an explanation. Cant you sit down and write a post that is clear?

Comment: you do not need to know what BitmapProvider is because it does not arrive at bitmap.compress,
photoUri is a content uri, so, to get the real path i need the cursor

Comment: For what do you need a real path? Wel you did strang react on BitmapProvider but have a look at that code. If it is ok then it did not need a 'real path' to read the file to construct a bitmap but used the uri directly. So why would you do it differently?

Comment: if i use a content uri in `new File(photoUri)`, the `new FileOutputStream(file)` return an `open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)` exception

Comment: Of course as you cannot use the File class for a content scheme uri. Now its really time you deep into BitmapProvider class to see how they did it.

Comment: post `getBitmap`, even if I don't know what it can do

Comment: `inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(photoUri);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);` Well you should always use that code as it uses your uri directly. In the same way there is openOutputStream. Throw away that bitmap provider. Use only these two lines.

Comment: but I need the file to understand its size. with `contentResolver.openOutputStream (photoUri)` how do I get its size

Comment: You would need to use an inputstream then to begin with. And not even a stream at all. But why do you need to know the file size if you have already the bitmap? And you did not tell in your post that you needed the file size although you were asked to tell what your code should do. You can get the file size from the uri directly. You dont need a stream first.

Answer (score -2):

If you request legacy storage you also have to get storage permission:
`android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`.

If you target API 30 `requestLegacyExternalStorage` doesn't work. You need to either set the target SDK to 29 or use media storage API.

Comment: where is the documentation of media storage api? I seem to have already followedit for file recovery ...

Comment: and even bringing back the target version I get the same result