# retrieve bitmap from Uri is empty sometimes

Tags: android, bitmap, uri

I select an image from gallery and intent its Uri to another activity.

```
  Uri imageUri = data.getParcelableExtra("path");
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditImageActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("uri", imageUri + "");
            startActivity(intent);
```

then in other activity using this code, I convert Uri to bitmap and set it to image view.

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse(intent.getStringExtra("uri"));

                    Bitmap bitmap = decodeUriToBitmap(uri);
                    bitmap = resizeBitmap(bitmap, MAX_SIZE, MAX_SIZE);


                    matrix = getMatrix(bitmap, imgForground);


                    imgForground.setImageMatrix(matrix);
                    RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions().disallowHardwareConfig();

                     Glide.with(EditImageActivity.this)
                            .load(bitmap)
                            .apply(options)
                             .centerInside()
                            .into(imgForground);
```

for converting Uri to bitmap, I use this code:

```
  public Bitmap decodeUriToBitmap(Uri sendUri) throws IOException {
    Bitmap getBitmap = null;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        getBitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(ImageDecoder.createSource(getContentResolver(), sendUri));
    } else {
        getBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), sendUri);
    }
    return getBitmap;
}
```

but this problem is not always. sometimes its is empty and sometimes not and also it is for android 9 and I check with lower version and there was not any problem.
here is the empty image that set to image view. I get it from debug mode.
[image of empty bitmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7Js2.jpg)

Comment: You say empty but do you mean bitmap==null ?

Comment: Further we have no idea what ImageDecoder.createSource() would do.

Comment: `Uri imageUri = data.getParcelableExtra("path")` Normally one would use just Uri uri = data.getData();

Comment: @blackapps what ImageDecoder.createSource() use to convert uri to bitmap

Comment: No. Creating a bitmap is done by .decodeBitmap(). But.. react to my first comment first.

Comment: @blackapps I edit my question and add the content of bitmap that is set to image view

Comment: I am waiting for reaction on my first comment only.

Comment: no it is not null, it just doesn't show anything

Comment: Read this post to see how you only need two code lines to create a bitmap: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66042220/android-10-mediastore-file-permission?noredirect=1#comment116770170_66042220

Comment: "I select an image from gallery and intent its Uri to another activity." -- I recommend not doing that. Use one activity, perhaps with multiple fragments. If you really feel that multiple activities is the correct solution, pass the `Uri` in the "data" facet of the `Intent` (`intent.setData(uri)`), and add `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` and/or `FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION` to the `Intent`. See https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/08/uri-access-lifetime-still-shorter-than-you-might-think.html for more.

Comment: @blackapps thanks. it works fine. It was about one week that i tried to solve it. your solution works fine.

Comment: @CommonsWare why do you recommend to use one activity?

Comment: Partly, because that is the direction that Android has been trending in for a couple of years, and that will only become stronger. Partly, it avoids the headache of passing a `Uri` to content between activities.