# Access the last image in user's gallery and show it in ImageView without selecting

Tags: java, android

I want to show the last image from user's gallery and show it in the ImageView. I used below code but got no success after all.

```
private void getLastGalleryImage() {
        // Find the last picture
        String[] projection = new String[]{
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.MIME_TYPE
        };

        final Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver()
                .query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null,
                        null, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC");

        // Put it in the image view
        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                String imageLocation = cursor.getString(1);
                File imageFile = new File(imageLocation);
                if (imageFile.exists()) {
                    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageLocation);
                    galleryImageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What I want to achieve is shown in the image below:

[image]

Comment: `want to show the last image from user's gallery` What do you consiter to be 'a last image' ? And what do you consider to be 'the last image'?

Comment: @blackapps By last image I mean the latest image by date in the user's gallery

Comment: It is unclear if you get no cursor or such or that you cannot load the image. You let us guess . And looking at your image ii have no idea what you want. And also which Android version on used devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code to obtain a bitmap instance is wrong (as it is useless for Android 10 and 11) where you use the File class.

Better use ._ID column to construct the uri for the file and then use the two code lines mentioned in: [Android 10 MediaStore file permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66042220/android-10-mediastore-file-permission?noredirect=1#comment116770170_66042220)

Comment: Thank you sir, I achieved what I wanted with `requestLegacyExternalStorage` but the issue now is it safe for API levels below 29? Or how I can achieve the same for API levels below 29? After the reply I will accept the answer

Comment: The best you can do is use the .ID column to construct an uri and then those two code lines. Will work for all Android versions. You never need that .DATA column or a File class. Your code will be much cleaner ;-).

Comment: Thank you again sir, you saved me a lot of time :)

Comment: You do not even have to construct a bitmap as once you have the uri ( one line) you could use galleryImageView.setImageUri(uri); So all in two lines of code.